# I am trying to code a BMI Calculator, the code is finished but it gives error, please help me to find the bug and fix it

Tags: python

```
BMI = 0

weight = int(input())  # weight in kg

height = float(input())  # height in m

BMI = weight / height ** 2

if BMI < 18.5:

    print("Underweight")

elif BMI <= 18.5 and BMI > 25:

    print("Normal")

elif BMI >= 25 and BMI < 30:

    print("Overweight")

else:

    print("Obesity")
```

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: Do you not see a contradiction between "the code is finished" and "it gives error"?

Comment: Your middle `elif` is impossible, there is no number that is both less than 18.5 *and* greater than 25

Answer (score 2):

Your first `elif` statement

```
elif BMI <= 18.5 and BMI > 25:
```

needs to be changed like this

```
elif BMI >= 18.5 and BMI < 25:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think answer by @python-learner is the one you want (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501575/218663) but I want to show you an alternative that I use frequently to make these kind of range rests easier. Let's use a function to get the proper text. Then we can rely on the ability to `return` from this function that makes our range tests easier to follow:

```py
def bmi_result(bmi):
    if bmi < 18.5:
        return "Underweight"

    if bmi < 25:
        return "Normal"

    if bmi < 30:
        return "Overweight"

    return "Obesity"
```

Drop a comment on this answer so I know you got it and I will delete it. It was a little too much to put in a comment to your question and the answer you want is again by @python-learner